# Add columns dynamically based on a condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm using SSMS 2012. Consider a table A with columns A, B, C. I would like to dynamically add a new column, D to this table based on a condition in one of the existing columns. How can this be achieved?

Query looks like the following,
select col1, col2 from #temptbl

To this #temptbl, I would like to add a column, col3 and the value in col3 is based on a condition on col2.

Comment: Have you tried anything with the stored procedures. if the number of coulmns are same for each table this can be done

Comment: Do you mean adding a column only to records that fit the condition? In that case it is not possible. You would have to add the column for the whole table. It would be better to add the column anyway and set the value for the column based on the condition (calculated field maybe)

Comment: @Tom: Yeah that's what I meant. Add a column and return values in that column based on the condition. How can this be done?

Comment: Alter the table and add the column. Then do an update statement with a case expression. Unless you give us some details about your table and the logic that is best anybody can offer.

Comment: @SeanLange I've modified my question with a sample query. Could you please assist me on this now?

Answer (score 3):

After your edit it is still incredibly vague what you want to do but maybe this is close??? No idea what the condition or the output should be but when the condition is not met the output of this will be NULL.

```
select col1
    , col2 
    , case when SomeCondition then SomeValue end as Col3
from #temptbl
```

Answer (score 3):

To add a column, you need to [`ALTER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(v=sql.100).aspx) the table

Let say you want to add an integer for `COL3`

```
ALTER TABLE #temptbl
ADD col3 INTEGER
```

And to update the value in col3 based on a condition on col2, you need to do an [`UPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523(v=sql.100).aspx) and use a [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.100).aspx) statement to check the condition :

Let say you want to set value 3 in `COL3` if `COL2` is equal to 2

```
UPDATE #temptbl
SET col3 = CASE WHEN col2 = 2 THEN 3 ELSE null END
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Tom mentioned, you can only had a column for the whole table, not on a conditional basis.  You can make it a computed column or when you query the table, have a `CASE` statement if adding a column is not possible.

Comment: I'm trying to add a column to a temporary table. That's the issue. I'm not sure how to add a column to a temporary table and do a conditional query on that column

Comment: Query looks like the following,

select col1, col2
from #temptbl

To this #temptbl, I would like to add a column, col3 and the value in col3 is based on a condition on col2.

Comment: Like Tom said, "It would be better to add the column anyway and set the value for the column based on the condition"